# Trace32 practice script: DATA.SET how to use

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

What does the following command mean? What does EA mean?

```
&HEAD=0x146BF94C
DATA.SET  EA:&HEAD+0x4  %LONG  DATA.LONG(EA:&HEAD+0x4)&0xFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `Data.Set` writes raw data to your target's memory at the given address.

The command follows this schema:
  **Data.Set** *<address> <access width> <data>* 
where

- *<address>* has the form *<access class>* **:** *<address offset>*
  where the "access class" are several letters specifying which memory is accessed in which way.
- *<access width>* is `%Byte` for 8-bit, `%Word` for 16-bit, `%Long` for 32-bit or `%Quad` for 64-bit
- *<data>* is the data you actually want to write.

For the "access class" check the chapter Access Classes in your Processor Architecture Manual (menu → Help → Processor Architecture Manual). The types of available access classes vary from the used processor architecture. (e.g. different classes for ARM and PowerPC)

The "access class" **EA:** means:

- Access the memory while the CPU is running (**E**).
- Access the memory via absolute (physical) memory addresses (**A**) bypassing the MMU.

Finally the data (*<data>*) you want to write to the memory can be a fixed value (e.g. 0x42) or calculated via an expression (0x40+0x02). Such an expression can also use so called "PRACTICE functions". The function used in your example is  `Data.Long(<address>)`, which reads 32-bit from the given address.
(Note: Expressions may not contain blanks.)

And then you have a macro `&HEAD=` which contains the string "0x146BF94C". This means that any `&HEAD` appearing in any later command gets replaces by the content of the macro. This similar to the C-Preprossor.

Thus, your commands

```
&HEAD=0x146BF94C
DATA.SET EA:&HEAD+0x4 %LONG DATA.LONG(EA:&HEAD+0x4)&0xFFFFFF
```

have the same meaning than

```
Data.Set  EA:0x146BF950  %LONG  Data.Long(EA:0x146BF950)&0x00FFFFFF
```

and that defines actually a read-modify-write on the 32-bit value at address EA:0x146BF950:  The value is read from memory, the upper 8-bit are set to zero and than the result gets written back to the same memory location.

It has (almost) the same meaning than the C code expression

```
*((volatile uint32_t*) 0x146BF950)  &=  0x00FFFFFF;
```

It is just "almost the same" because the C code expression would not bypass the MMU, like your Data.Set command does, thanks to the "A" in the memory access class of the addresses.